# Access firebase secret for my project

Tags: firebase, zapier, firebase-console

I am trying to enable zapier to access firebase database of my project. I am not able to get the details they are asking for.

The zapier page says

[image: help menu from zapier asking firebase secret]

On the firebase authentication tab (I couldn't find auth) I don't see anything named Forge

[image: Firebase console for the project]

Any suggestions on how to get this Firebase secret?

Comment: Firebase is moving to a new authentication system. We're planning on updating our app, but in the meantime the database credentials have become a little bit harder to find.

To find your database secret, follow these instructions:

1. Click on the settings/cog wheel icon next to your project name at the top of the new Firebase Console
2. Click Project settings
3. Click on the Service Account tab
4. Click on the Database Secrets link in the inner left-nav
5. Hover over the non-displayed secret and click Show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the right hand side of the project, click the `Settings` icon.

1) The API key should be available in `General` tab

2) The database secret should be present in `Database` tab

[image: Settings Icon]